# How can I make all my grid column have their height be equal to the height of shortest column

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

As you can see in my snippet, both columns are getting their heights set to the height of the tallest column. I however want my columns to have their heights set to the shortest column, where the second column would have overflow scroll instead.

I do not know the height of either of the columns as their content is loaded in dynamically.

I also do not need to use grid if flex can acheive my desired result.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.item1 {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
.item2 {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <div class='item1_content'>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item2'>
    <div class='item2_content'>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not something CSS can do by itself. What would set the height limit that would trigger the overflow on the taller box? There's nothing. Need a script.

Comment: Do you know which one will be the shortest? If yes, there is a CSS solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, the right one will always be shortest in my case

Comment: see the duplicate then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript for this.
I think there isn't a CSS only solution for this :)

```js
let referenceBox = document.getElementsByClassName("item1_content")[0];
let adjustedBox = document.getElementsByClassName("item2_content")[0];

adjustedBox.style.height = referenceBox.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.item1 {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
.item2 {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='item1'>
    <div class='item1_content'>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item2'>
    <div class='item2_content'>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```